# Escape characters SQL on Names for Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

Let say you wanted to grant privelages to a users to your database.  Now suppose the users are Wilson and Grant.  Well as you know "Grant" is a reserved word for SQL.  But sometimes people do have a last name "Grant".  How would you do that.

```
GRANT SELECT ON WAREHOUSE TO WILSON, _______________;
```

???

I'm using Oracle, but if you could tell me what it would be for mysql as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you put the names in quotes:

```
GRANT SELECT ON WAREHOUSE to 'grant'@localhost;
```

I'll bet it's similar in Oracle.